# getArguments() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

getArguments() returns the correct JSON string the first time OnCreateView() is called for Frag1 but not when I swipe to Frag2 and OnCreateView() for Frag1 is called again. Instead, the "JSON" argument is null.

Activity:

```
SparkleViewPagerLayout sparkleViewPagerLayout = (SparkleViewPagerLayout) 
findViewById(R.id.view_pager_layout);
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
sparkleViewPagerLayout.getViewPager().setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch (pos) {
                case 0:
                    return Frag0.newInstance(json0);
                case 1:
                    return Frag1.newInstance(json1); // <--THE FAILING FRAGMENT
                case 2:
                    return Frag2.newInstance(json2);
                case 3:
                    return Frag3.newInstance(json3);
                default:
                    return Frag0.newInstance(json0);
            }
        }
    });
```

Fragment:

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
private ArrayList<Thing> things;
private Gson gson = new Gson();

public static Frag1 newInstance(String json) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("JSON", json);
    args.putInt("background", R.drawable.img_thing_bg_blurred);
    Frag1 fragment = new Frag1();
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.thing_detailed, parent, false);
    int background = getArguments().getInt("background");
    Util.setBackground(v, background, getContext());

    String json = getArguments().getString("JSON");
    things = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Thing>>() {
    }.getType());

    setUpThingOne(v);

    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    Fragment listFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.thingFragmentListContainer);
    // We removed the thing in position one, need to update the JSON to reflect this change.
    String jsonNew = gson.toJson(things);
    if (listFragment == null) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("THINGLIST", jsonNew);
        listFragment = new ThingListFragment();
        listFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.ThingFragmentListContainer, listFragment)
                .commit();
    }

    return v;
}

    private void setUpThingOne(View v) {
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.thingName);
        TextView type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.thingField);
        ImageView dollarImg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thingPrice);
        ImageView bgImg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thingBg);

        for (Thing thing : things) {
            if (thing.getPosition() == 1) {
                name.setText(thing.getName());
                type.setText(thing.getField());
                Util.setDollarImage(getContext(), dollarImg, thingSpot.getPrice());
                RequestUtil.getImage2(getContext(), thing.getImage_url(), bgImg);

                //Remove the #1 thing so that we can make a fragment list from the others.
                //things.remove(thing);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Crash log:

```
01-28 13:43:08.117 31378-31378/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.test, PID: 31378
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.ArrayList.iterator()' on a null object reference
       at com.test.test.fragments.Frag1.setUpThingOne(Frag1.java:78)
       at com.test.test.fragments.Frag1.onCreateView(Frag1.java:48)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:251)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: post the code for `Frag1` (since this is the one that is failing)

Comment: You can't return an instance of Frag2 if newInstance method should return Frag1

Comment: Edited again. Sorry about not being careful editing the first time!

Comment: Np. The fragment seems to be ok now. Are you sure that json1 is not null when you add it to args?

Comment: Yes. The json is there perfectly fine the first time and then null when I swipe away.

Comment: I mean at this line: return Frag1.newInstance(json1); ... Did you check if the json1 is not null?

Comment: Just double checked. The JSON is definitely there at that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ends up I was not very careful when I did some copy pasting. I thought it was weird that onCreateView() was being called for Frag1 when I was swiping to Frag2 and I realized I was creating a new Frag1 in Frag2 instead of Frag2...Many hours wasted on something that should have never happened!

Comment: Wow,  I am glad that you figured out :).

Answer (score 0):

The view pager stores your fragments in memory. It can be that the method `newInstance` just runs for the first time the fragment is created. When it is not visible on screen, its `onDestroyView()` may be called then when it is visible again and the `onCreateView()` callback is called (`newInstance` will be never triggered). That explains why the arguments on `onCreateView()` are null. You call put `log` in all fragment callbacks to see the states of your fragment. Check [Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for more detail on fragment life-cycle.

Comment: onCreateView() on Frag1 is being called when I swipe away to Frag2. I don't even get to swipe it back in because the app crashes while I'm swiping to Frag2. In addition, the "background" int argument is still there. Only the JSON becomes null.

Comment: @Jonfor, how is your `json` initialized? You can put `log` to see how many times the `newInstance` method is executed at pos `1`?

Comment: newInstance is called once. The json is being sent in from another activity and is placed in the new activity's onCreate(): `final String json1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("JSON");`

Comment: Ok, that fine. We need to know why the onCreateView is called the second time. Could you post the post `crash log` when you swipe to Frag2.

Comment: Added the crash log.